# How to make a pen drive as a RAM in an Ubuntu operating system

Tags: ram

I have seen a way to increase the RAM using a pen drive if the RAM of a computer with Windows operating system is not enough, but can it be done on a computer with Ubuntu operating system? If anyone knows, can you explain to me how? Thank you.

Comment: *I have seen a way to increase the RAM using a pen drive if the RAM of a computer with Windows operating system is not enough* No, you didn't, what you might have seen is clickbait. The usage of external media for pagefile, ReadyBoost or with 3rd party software  does not and could not increase RAM. It deals with virtual memory and is extremely slow. Ubuntu already does that with a proper swapfile or swap partition.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? If you don't have at least 4 GB, use Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.

Comment: I have 4GB RAM. I increased the 2GB in the swap to 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increase RAM with a pen drive. At most, you could increase available swap space with a pen drive. Swap space on disk is space where information in RAM temporarily can be stored when it is not needed to increase available RAM for other processes.

Consider increasing swap on your internal hard drive first before considering installing SWAP on a removable medium of unknown quality, performance and reliability.

Comment: With a pendrive it is very likely that 'unknown' means 'bad' quality, performance and reliability compared to an SSD or HDD.